# How to change the BottomNavigationBar after a Navigator.push?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, navbar

I would like to set a new BottomNavigationBar after i've clicked on one of my ListTile. Right now, i am getting two BottomNavigationbar after I've clicked on one of them.

Below is my code where I setup the first bar:

```
class CoachNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoachNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CoachNav> createState() => _CoachNavState();
}

class _CoachNavState extends State<CoachNav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const TeamListView(),
    const SettingsFormView(),
  ];

  Widget? _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.groups),
            label: "Mes équipes",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Paramètres"),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then, there is the code where I setup the second bar:

```
class TeamNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const TeamNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TeamNav> createState() => _TeamNavState();
}

class _TeamNavState extends State<TeamNav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const PlayersListView(),
    const GamesListView(),
  ];

  Widget? _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.group),
            label: "Mes joueurs",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.sports_basketball), label: "Mes matchs"),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are two screenshots of what is happening

First Bar

[image]

Second Bar

[image]

---------------- EDIT ----------------------

This is what I get when I make the _widgetOptions texts

[I got the first bar... whith the content from where the second bar should Appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyQNA.png)

this is the snippet of the code I got as answer below:

```
    lass App extends StatelessWidget {
      const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(home: CoachNav());
      }
    }
    
    class TeamNav extends StatefulWidget {
      const TeamNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<TeamNav> createState() => _TeamNavState();
    }
    
    class _TeamNavState extends State<TeamNav> {
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
    
      final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
        Text("PlayersListView"),
        Text("PlayersListView"),
      ];
    
      Widget? _onItemTap(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
        return null;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
     /*     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CoachNav(),
            ));
          }),*/
          body: Container(
            child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.group),
                label: "Mes joueurs",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.sports_basketball), label: "Mes matchs"),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTap,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class CoachNav extends StatefulWidget {
      const CoachNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<CoachNav> createState() => _CoachNavState();
    }
    
    class _CoachNavState extends State<CoachNav> {
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
    
      final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
        Text("PlayersListView"),
        Text("PlayersListView"),
      ];
    
      Widget? _onItemTap(int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = index;
        });
        return null;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
          ),
          //floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.groups),
                label: "Mes équipes",
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Paramètres"),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTap,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

```
This is the code that have the text shown in the third screenshot.
```

```
    class PlayersListView extends StatelessWidget {
      const PlayersListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(body: Text("Playerslist"),);
      }
    }
```

Comment: what will happen on scaffold body? Are you trying to archive `Second Bar`, What are you expecting

Comment: When I click on one of the tiles in the first screenshot, I Navigator.push to a new page (the second piece of code) and that new page is supposed to have a new bottomNavigationPage. But right now, I have one bar over the other. I would like to keep only the one that is on the top of the other in the second screenshot.

Comment: Sound like you have nested scaffold!

Comment: Do you have any scaffold on `TeamListView`

Comment: Yes I have a scafffold on TeamListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a solution, I simply needed to add "rootNavigator: true" to my Navigator.push. It works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a design problem.

In your case, the best way is this one, i think.

When you tap on a tile you should fix a flag and rebuild your page instead of navigating to a new route.

Then, when building your `BottomNavigationBarItem`list check the flag and add or remove `BottomNavigationBarItem` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra scaffold from `_widgetOptions` children that contains bottomNavBar. Follow the snippet pattern

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: TeamNav());
  }
}

class TeamNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const TeamNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TeamNav> createState() => _TeamNavState();
}

class _TeamNavState extends State<TeamNav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text("PlayersListView"),
    Text(" GamesListView()"),
  ];

  Widget? _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CoachNav(),
        ));
      }),
      body: Container(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.group),
            label: "Mes joueurs",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.sports_basketball), label: "Mes matchs"),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CoachNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoachNav({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CoachNav> createState() => _CoachNavState();
}

class _CoachNavState extends State<CoachNav> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text("TeamListView"),
    Text("SettingsFormView"),
  ];

  Widget? _onItemTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {}),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.groups),
            label: "Mes équipes",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Paramètres"),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What am I suppose to replace the scaffold with in the childrens? I have a lot of code in them ^^'

Comment: Check the code of `PlayersListView` and `GamesListView`... if they contain any `bottomNavigationBar`  remove that part

Comment: Ok so I have copy/paste your code (I just changed the "home:" value to CoachNav();). I am still getting the double bottom bar when I click on my tile. should I change the value of the Navigator Push ?

Comment: `home` means materialApp?

Comment: Yeah, so I changed your "home: TeamNav()" to "home:CoachNav()" because "CoachNav" is the first I want to reach. Right now, when I press a tile, I ask to push to "TeamNav()" but I still get the double bar

Comment: Can you recheck your `_widgetOptions` children containing navbar or not.

Comment: I have in total 4 WidgetOptions children. all 4 have Scaffold but none of them have a navBar or BottomNavigationBar.

Comment: Can you comment the navbar on current scaffolds, means `TeamNav` and `CoachNav` s scaffold. Also do you get the same error from above snippet

Comment: When I comment the BottomNavigationBars everywhere but your snippet I get the same error. So my user logs in, he is now on the page with the CoachNav BottomBarNavigationBar. When he tap on a team name from the listTile, he gets to "TeamNav(); and the second BottomNavigationBar is created but the first one still remains.

Comment: OK, how replace all `_widgetOptions` with Text widget same me. can you find duplicate now

Comment: Ok so when I do that, I only have the first BottomNavigationBar (with "Mes équipes" and "Réglages" Icons label) but the screen shows the content from the page where the second BottomNavigatorBar is supposed to show. So I have the first bar, but the second screenshot content (not my listTile, just the text "PlayerList")

Comment: Can you share full snippet, Im not getting

Comment: NO issue, try `flutter clean` and rebuild app, better separate the project test your current snippet , if nothing works do `flutter upgrage`